# Windows Forms: Keeping Check Beside Checked Box list item and displaying separate message for each

Tags: vb.net, winforms, messagebox, checkboxlist

When I run my program currently, Within any checked box list I am unable to actually select an option (i.e. the box beside it, to tick).

I would also like each individual option to display a messagebox when ticked (i.e. "User story one added"),  But currently my program only displays a general messagebox ("User Story selected") once the checked box list is clicked on. Any help would be much appreciated!

Current Code:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MessageBox.Show("User Story Selected")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You are responding to the wrong event and might be likely to examine the wrong property.

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("User Story Selected")
End Sub
```

Checks fire the `ItemCheck` event, and checked items are in the `CheckedItems` Collection.  The `SelectedItems` collection is literally those selected (highlighted) which might not also be checked. It is not really a list of checkboxes, but a list of items drawn as checks - thats why they look different than regular checks.  To see which item:

```
For n as Integer = 0  to CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count-1
    userWants = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n)
Next n
```

Like a ListBox you can put anything in there, not just strings, so it was a list of stories, you might be able to do:

```
 userWants = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n).StoryName
```

Comment: Thanks, I am only new to c# so please bear with me. Does the above code allow me to create a specific message depending on user story is selected?

Comment: it can/should.  it depends on how they are associated with the control.  `n` in the for loop would be an index, so that could be one way; another would be if the name were part of the object added to the Items collection (see `StoryName` example).  Oh, yea - this is VB code (as is yours), but easily translated.

Comment: @RNI2013 When I firstly saw your question with the C# tag on it, I thought that it was a "typo". But after reading this last comment I am not too sure about that. Do you seriously think that your code is C#?!

Comment: Im not sure, I have literally started using winForms today and assumed it was c#, can u advise me as to what language it is?

Comment: It is VB but the C# code would be **very** similar since they are both using .NET

Comment: OK so the language I am currently using to make these forms is .NET? I am have (10 weeks) experience in Java and have never tried another language so excuse my ignorance!

Comment: No, the language above is VB. C# looks very similar to it.  The platform is .NET - that is, the CheckedList box is something in a .NET lib or assembly and we are implementing it using C# or VB.